# Time Delay After User Input

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a `EditText` box and the user types a string and the string is sent to a database and the `UI` is updated. I used the `TextChanged` function and the function works properly. However rather than updating the `UI` after each keystroke I want to wait 1/2 a second after the last keystroke to update the string to send to the database. Any suggestions on implementation?

```
editText.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    string text = editText.Text.ToString();                  
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can do it:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(

    public void run(){

       // your update code here..

    }

), 2000);
```

*2000* represents the number of milliseconds before the code will run.. so in this case is 2 seconds.

Though I think you might try to think to a better idea of saving the data, like using `onFocusChangeListener` on the `EditText` and save the data after the `EditText` looses focus..

**EDIT:**

Of course the above code should be put in the text changed callback method and you should also make sure the timer won't be called on each key pressed..

Comment: I am new to this but I dont think onFocusChangeListener would work here. It is a single search bar that shows a list of items. Upon typing the list is narrowed down to only contain strings that begin with the characters entered. I want the page to be updated after user has stopped typing for 1/2 a second.

Comment: You are right about the onFocusChangeListener in your case, but you could update the results on each even or odd character number.. I don't recommend you to use the delay as I don't think is a good solution for you..

Comment: i have same problem, this code will always call run(), when you type fast, not good idea

Comment: my answer mayble help you, when input fast => nothing send, stop input 1s => send your request
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007614/how-to-delay-second-when-search-text-change

Answer (score 0):

You can do following before updating the ui

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Upadating your ui

                }

            }, 500);
```

Comment: Please note that doing that on the Main Thread (UI Thread) will freeze the user actions for 500 milliseconds or as much as the sleep method is set..

Comment: calling sleep will block the ui thread. should not call thread.sleep. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip. It was really helpful. See my edited answer is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

We can actually use text-watcher override functions to solve this problem

Below is an example as to how it can be done

Also attached link with complete description

```
 private EditText searchText;  
 private TextView resultText;  
 private Timer timer;

      private TextWatcher searchTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {  
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // user typed: start the timer
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              // do required 
            }
        }, 400); // 400ms delay to before executing run, if user stops typing after 400ms function will get fired
    }

     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

     }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // reset timer if user is typing
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
};
```

source : [delayed edit text](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-how-to-delay-changedtextevent-on-androids-edittext)